# Monte Carlo simulation for tossing a coin to get a certain pattern

Tags: excel, vba, montecarlo, probability-theory

Inspired by this article: [Statistics of Coin-Toss Patterns](https://blog.drskippy.com/2008/04/03/statistics-of-coin-toss-patterns/), I have conducted a Monte Carlo simulation for determining the expected number of tossing a coin to get a certain pattern by using Excel VBA. The following code is the Monte Carlo simulation for tossing **a fair coin** to get pattern HTH, where H is head (1) and T is tail (0).

```
Sub Tossing_Coin()
    Dim Toss(1000000) As Double, NToss(1000000) As Double, AVToss(1000000) As Double
    t0 = Timer
    Sheet2.Cells.Clear
    a = 0

    For j = 1 To 1000000

        p1 = Rnd()
        If p1 <= 0.5 Then
            Toss(1) = 1
        Else
            Toss(1) = 0
        End If

        p2 = Rnd()
        If p2 <= 0.5 Then
            Toss(2) = 1
        Else
            Toss(2) = 0
        End If

        i = 2
        Do
            p3 = Rnd()
            If p3 <= 0.5 Then
                Toss(i + 1) = 1
            Else
                Toss(i + 1) = 0
            End If

            i = i + 1
        Loop Until Toss(i - 2) = 1 And Toss(i - 1) = 0 And Toss(i) = 1

        NToss(j) = i
        a = a + NToss(j)
        AVToss(j) = a / j
        b = AVToss(j)
    Next j

    MsgBox "The expected number of tossing is " & b & "." _
        & vbNewLine & "The running time of simulation is " & Round(Timer - t0, 2) & " s."
End Sub
```

The output of the program is as shown below:

[image]

which agrees with the result as shown in the article. Other patterns for tossing a fair coin are also match. Despite the results, I'm still feeling uncertain whether the program I wrote is correct or not. My doubt arises when the coin is unfair, meaning `p1`, `p2`, and `p3` are not equal to 0.5, since I don't have any information to check its accuracy. I also want to know how to write an efficient program in VBA Excel or R to perform simulation above for a longer pattern like THTHTHTHT, THTTHHTHTTH, etc. and its looping is more than 1,000,000 (maybe 100,000,000 or 1,000,000,000) but still pretty fast? Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it more efficient, you could use the bits of a variable by assigning a bit with a toss. Then for each toss, rotate the bits on the left and add the toss result at the first position until the bits on the right are a match with the pattern :

```
pattern "HTH"  : 101
mask for "XXX" : 111

1 toss "H" :       1 And 111 = 001
2 toss "T" :      10 And 111 = 010
3 toss "T" :     100 And 111 = 100
4 toss "H" :    1001 And 111 = 001
5 toss "H" :   10011 And 111 = 011
6 toss "T" :  100110 And 111 = 110
7 toss "H" : 1001101 And 111 = 101  : "HTH" matches the first 3 bits
```

Note that VBA doesn't have a bit shift operator, but shifting 1 bit on the left is the same as multiplying by 2 :

```
  decimal  9 =   1001 in bits
 9 +  9 = 18 =  10010 in bits
18 + 18 = 36 = 100100 in bits
```

Here is an example to get the average number of toss to match a sequence:

```vb
Sub UsageExample()
    Const sequence = "HTH"
    Const samples = 100000

    MsgBox "Average: " & GetTossingAverage(sequence, samples)
End Sub

Function GetTossingAverage(sequence As String, samples As Long) As Double
    Dim expected&, tosses&, mask&, tossCount#, i&
    Randomize ' Initialize the random generator. '

    ' convert the [TH] sequence to a sequence of bits. Ex: HTH -> 00000101 '
    For i = 1 To Len(sequence)
        expected = expected + expected - (Mid$(sequence, i, 1) = "T")
    Next

    ' generate the mask for the rotation of the bits. Ex: HTH -> 01110111 '
    mask = (2 ^ (Len(sequence) * 2 + 1)) - (2 ^ Len(sequence)) - 1

    ' iterate the samples '
    For i = 1 To samples
        tosses = mask

        ' generate a new toss until we get the expected sequence '
        Do
            tossCount = tossCount + 1
            ' rotate the bits on the left and rand a new bit at position 1 '
            tosses = (tosses + tosses - (Rnd < 0.5)) And mask
        Loop Until tosses = expected
    Next

    GetTossingAverage = tossCount / samples
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but can you give extra comments on each lines since I don't get it on some parts like: `expected = expected + expected - (Mid$(sequence, i, 1) = "T")`,  `mask = (2 ^ (Len(sequence) * 2 + 1)) - (2 ^ Len(sequence)) - 1`, etc. Anyway, how can you ensure the answer is still correct if I change the probability of getting head, for example: p=0.3? Is there a mathematical proof to support your simulation?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need one string to store pattern you want to find.

Then after each toss append latest result onto end of results string.

Then check if last n digits of results string == pattern where n = length of pattern.

If match then record numbers of tosses and blank results string and go again ...

You could probably do it in about 20 lines of code! Hope that helps.

Comment: I'd appreciate if you're able to provide a 20-lines of code as you claimed. Thanks